# Does $c^2 \leq a^2 + b^2$ hold for right triangles on the sphere?

Tags: triangles, 3d, noneuclidean-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I was hoping for a proof of something which appears to be intuitive to me, but which I can't prove.

> Let $a, b$ & $c$ be lengths of the sides of a triangle. We know that on a plane, $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ when $C$ is a right angle.
>
> Does a similar identity $c^2 \leq a^2 + b^2$ hold on a sphere?

On a sphere, when $a$, $b$ or both are $0$, then $c^2=a^2 + b^2$. For practical case $a>0$ and $b>0$, and $C$ being a right angle , $c^2$ has always been less than $a^2 + b^2$ for whatever examples I have tried.

I have read the Pythagorean theorem, the sine rule, the cosine rule, and other basic identities for spherical triangles, but I have not been able to prove this particular identity.

In case the identity what I'm trying to prove does not hold, would appreciate a counter example.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I had read the law of cosines, but didn't think of using the Maclaurin series! I guess that a more rigorous proof exists, but this is good enough for me - I needed an upper bound on the hypotenuse. I knew that I was missing something, thanks very much for the link!

Comment: Search "spherical geometry" and "triangles" and you'll see the answer.

Comment: @ranban282: Welcome to Math.SE! ... *"We know that on a plane, $c^2\leq a^2+b^2$."* ... Ummm ... If the angle opposite $c$ is obtuse, then $c^2>a^2+b^2$.

Comment: The reason you have not been able to prove it is that is doesn't hold on a sphere. The spherical law of cosines is the fundamental formula for spherical triangles. From it you get the spherical triangle inequality: $$\cos(b+c) < \cos a < \cos(b-c)$$ and the spherical equivalent of the Pythagorean theorem for right triangles (where $c$ subtends a right angle) $$\cos c = \cos a\cos b$$Note that on a sphere it is possible for two or even all three angles to be right.

Comment: @Blue Sorry, not quite sure what I was thinking when I posted the inequality for the plane.  I have edited it, hope it is now clear what I was asking, namely, is $c^2$ 's upper bound on a sphere is $a^2 + b^2$

Comment: Thanks everybody for helping me out with the formatting math symbols - I've always found very difficult to read up on my own. Think I've grasped it now.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I had misstated the problem. However, Search "spherical geometry" and "triangles" and you'll see the answer" does not help - I clearly stated that I did so.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the triangle inequality, hadn't come across that one before. But would appreaciate how we can use the inequality and the cosine rule/pythogoras theoream to show that the identity doesn't hold for . Or better still, a counterexample. Note that I goofed up of the inequality on the plane (corrected it since). But on the sphere, yet to find a case where the 'hypotenuse' excees the value provided by applying the pythogoras theorem for the plane. In fact it seems to be an upper bound.

Comment: Note that the sphere approximates a plane locally. If you limit your investigation to triangles in small neighborhoods of a point, you get almost planar behavior, with the approximation improving as the neighborhood gets smaller. Thus anything that is more than just barely false (i.e., no tiny change in values will make it true) for the plane is also false for the sphere. As you've now realized, the claim that $c^2 \le a^2 + b^2$ is false, and not just barely so, for obtuse triangles in the plane. So one way to find counter-examples in the sphere is too look at small obtuse triangles.

Comment: As for the planar Pythagorean theorem itself, practically any right triangle on the sphere will break it. I cannot believe your claim that you haven't found a counter-example. For example, the equilateral right spherical triangle formed by a pole and two points on the equator that are $90^\circ$ apart. $a, b, c$ are all the same size $> 0$. It is impossible for them to satisfy $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$

Comment: @PaulSinclair  If all the sides are of the same size a, and all three angles are  right angles, then clearly, $c^2$ ≤ $a2$+$b2$, as c=a=b. I've run a simulation with a point P on the earth in the northern hemisphere, a point Q, which is a point on the equator with the same longitude as P, and another point R on the equator. Here, Q is right angled. In no case do i see that $PR^2$ >=$PQ^2$ + $QR^2$. I also don't understand how the property is false for the plane - $c^2$ is exactly equal $a^2+b^2$ on the planel, when C is right angled. On the sphere it appears to be an upper bound.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Please note that I had misstated the original question, as I stated in an earlier comment, and have updated it. I'm only talking about right angled triangles on the plane. It is trivial to come up with counter examples where $c^2 \geq a^2 + b^2$ when C is obtuse on a sphere, but I have clearly stated that C is a right angle. $c^2$  roughly equals  $a^2 + b^2$ when a is very small as compared to b, and vice-versa. My intuitive understanding is that the "curvedness" of the sphere makes it an upper bound instead of an equality.

Comment: Wow, now you are being dishonest, pretending like you hadn't misstated your question again, and just changed it again AFTER my comments. Do not be snotty because I addressed the question you had asked, instead of the one you intended to ask. You did not "clearly state" anything. The answer to your CURRENT question is well-known, but after your nasty behavior, I feel no need to provide it. Perhaps someone who you haven't ticked off can tell you about curvature.